# How to check if tweet was successfully added? Which the id has new tweet?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

How can I to know if tweet was added successfully? Can I get user id which twitted some message from my web page?

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://google.com" data-text="title_test">Tweet</a>

<script>!function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
    if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = p + '://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }
}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
```